# ElementTree Python: How to extract siblings if siblings are nested?

Tags: xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have a XML file that I am trying to convert to an Excel dataset. The XML is arranged like this:

```
<XML Data>
    <Record>
        <ID>
            <Client id="01"></Client>
        </ID>
        <Service>
            <Product id="A"></Product>
            <Product id="B"></Product>
            <Product id="C"></Product>
        </Service>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <ID>
            <Client id="02"></Client>
        </ID>
        <Service>
            <Product id="A"></Product>
            <Product id="B"></Product>
            <Product id="Y"></Product>
        </Service>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <ID>
            <Client id="24"></Client>
        </ID>
        <Service>
            <Product id="U"></Product>
        </Service>
    </Record>
</XML Data>
```

As you can see, each record shows a single client with multiple services.

I'm trying to get this done using only ElementTree. This is incorrect code that returns ALL services for each client ID--I can't figure out how to get it to return each service that a client actually had:

```
for x in root.findall("Record/ID/Client"):
    client = x.get("id")
    for y in root.findall('.//Service/Product'):
        service = y.get("id")
        print(client, service)
```

I am trying to get it arranged like this in an CSV format:

```
ClientID    ServiceID
01          A
01          B
01          C
02          A
02          B
02          Y
24          U
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! I've looked up this, but could only find resources that show how to extract actual siblings--since the Client ID and Service ID are parents to the children I want to extract, this is proving to be a little more confusing. Thank you!

Comment: In the second for loop, try changing `root.findall` to `x.findall`. That way the xpath is relative to the current `x`.

Comment: Doing this resulted in there being no output at all for the second loop, so that does not seem to be it.

Comment: Oops sorry. For some reason I was thinking you were first selecting `Record` instead of `Client`. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of first selecting `Client`, first select `Record`.

Then your second for loop can be changed from `root.finall` to `x.findall` will only find `Product` elements for the current `Record`.

Example...

**XML Input** (test.xml; fixed invalid root element)

```xml
<XML_Data>
    <Record>
        <ID>
            <Client id="01"></Client>
        </ID>
        <Service>
            <Product id="A"></Product>
            <Product id="B"></Product>
            <Product id="C"></Product>
        </Service>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <ID>
            <Client id="02"></Client>
        </ID>
        <Service>
            <Product id="A"></Product>
            <Product id="B"></Product>
            <Product id="Y"></Product>
        </Service>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <ID>
            <Client id="24"></Client>
        </ID>
        <Service>
            <Product id="U"></Product>
        </Service>
    </Record>
</XML_Data>
```

**Python**

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('test.xml')

root = tree.getroot()

for x in root.findall("Record"):
    client = x.find("ID/Client").get("id")
    for y in x.findall('.//Service/Product'):
        service = y.get("id")
        print(client, service)
```

**Print Output**

```
01 A
01 B
01 C
02 A
02 B
02 Y
24 U
```

Comment: My goodness, such a simple fix! Thank you so much -- I tried nearly 20 other different ways and it turns out all I needed to do was start from a higher level!